# A way to justify interchanging a summation and integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, improper-integrals

For all real $a>0$ consider
$$\int_0^\infty x^a \left (\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n n e^{-2nx} \right ) \, dx.$$

I would like to interchange the summation with the integration in order to find its value but I am having trouble justifying such a change.

Fubini's theorem is not strong enough to justify the interchange for all $a > 0$. If we put absolute values on the terms, we have
$$\left | \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n n e^{-2nx} \right | \leqslant \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n e^{-2nx} = \frac{e^{2x}}{(e^{2x} - 1)^2}$$
but $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a e^{2x}}{(e^{2x} - 1)^2}~dx$ only converges for $a > 1$ and not for all $a > 0$.

So my question is, how can the interchange between the summation and integration be justified so that it holds for all $a > 0$?

Comment: Can probably use dominated convergence on the partial sums.

Comment: That sum can be computed, why do you want to integrate first?

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca Yes, I know that sum can be found. But I would like to find the integral by converting it to this exact sum, and then performing the interchange between the summation and the integration. It can be done, it is just I cannot fully justify what I am doing.

Comment: I overlooked that $e^{2x}/(e^{2x}-1)^2 \sim e^{2x}/x^2$ for $x$ close to $0$. I believe this is what was meant by the integral not converging for $a>0$, only $a > 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^k (-1)^n n e^{-2nx}=\frac{-e^{2x}}{(1+e^{2x})^2}+\frac{(-1)^k}{e^{2(k-1)x}(1+e^{2x})^2}+\frac{(-1)^kk}{e^{2kx}(1+e^{2x})}$$
Since $k\ge1$ and $\displaystyle\frac k{e^{2kx}}\le\frac k{2kx}=\frac1{2x}$, hence

$$\left|\sum_{n = 1}^k (-1)^n n e^{-2nx}\right|\le\frac{e^{2x}}{(1+e^{2x})^2}+\frac{1}{(1+e^{2x})^2}+\frac{1}{2x(1+e^{2x})}$$

further,

$$\left|x^a\cdot\sum_{n = 1}^k (-1)^n n e^{-2nx}\right|\le\frac{x^ae^{2x}}{(1+e^{2x})^2}+\frac{x^a}{(1+e^{2x})^2}+\frac{x^{a-1}}{2(1+e^{2x})}$$

Apparently, the RHS is convergent for $a>0$, hence we can switch the summation and integration.

Answer (score 6):

We can use the dominated convergence theorem to justify the interchange.

Let's denote $S_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^nne^{-2nx}$.

As $N$ is fixed,
$$S_N(x)=-\frac 12\frac d{dx}\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^ne^{-2nx}$$
$$=\frac{\big(1+(N+2)(-1)^Ne^{-2x(N+1)}\big)}{1+e^{2x}}-\frac{1+(-1)^Ne^{-2x(N+1)}}{(1+e^{2x})^2}$$
It is straightforward to see that for $N>3$
$$|S_N(x)|<e^{-2x}\Big(1+(N+3)e^{-2Nx}\Big)<e^{-2x}+2Ne^{-2Nx}e^{-2x}$$
Given that $2Nx<e^{2Nx}=1+2Nx+...$
$$|S_N(x)|<(1+1/x)\,e^{-2x}\tag{1}$$
Then
$$|I|=\int_0^\infty x^a|S_N(x)|dx<\int_0^\infty x^a\Big(1+\frac 1x\Big)e^{-2x}dx\tag{2}$$
It means that we constructed the dominating function $S(x)>x^a|S_N(x)|$ for all $N>3,\, a>0$

According to the DCT, we are allowed to take the limit under the integral sign:
$$\int_0^\infty x^a \Big(\lim_{N\to\infty}S_N(x)\Big)dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^\infty x^a \Big(S_N(x)\Big)dx$$